# Application of LASSO , Ridge, PLS in feature selection of spectral data

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, feature-selection, lasso, high-dimensional

The meatspec data in  faraway package is spectral data with 100 features .(215 *101). Use of LASSO over ridge and PLS gives better performance (RMSE based)
But none of the features are removed ( no beta is zero)?

Since X  is a spectral data. a absorbances across a range of 100 wavelengths 
The correlation natural exist among the features.
1. In case when no feature is reduced to zero, can the feature be selected
based on threshold (say chose features when coef is greater than 0.05)
2.How can LASSO be forced for shrinking coef to zero?
3. Say some values shrunk to zero. can lasso be used again to check for further shrinking?

Comment: From your comment to Peter's answer it sounds like your question is very different to the one stated. 'I want to know about the most relevant variables', is this the underlying motivation of the question? If so you are limiting the responses you can get. There are a lot of ways of understanding variable 'relevance' to the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the penalization coefficient lambda, this will remove variables. Of course you can use the lasso then again after removing the variables that have been set to 0 before, but with the lambda defined before it should give you a model with all variables included.

Comment: I want to know about the most relevant variables. I dont find it easy to keep increasing lambda unless the  RMSE is very satisfactory

Comment: Well its always a trade-off. It seems that always variable matter in your model. Did you check other lambda values to see if RMSE is satisfactory enough?
The most relevant variables are the ones with the highest coefficient (as you should have normalized the variables before).

Comment: Yes i checked other lambdas as well..10 lambdas to either end of lambda.min had similar results...but the non coef shrinked to zero..